# Wrong rendering (character set?) for the profile name in the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

First of all: the profile page is a very nice addition to the Android app. Thumbs up!

I want to report a very minor bug: my name contains an accent (Lorenzo Dematté). It is rendered correctly on the site, and also inside Q and A in the app, but it looks like `Lorenzo Dematt&#223;` on the left-side menu.

Comment: Just curious (no android for me) do you see hats in the app?

Comment: No, no hats.. feature request? :)

Comment: Uh oh, another encoding bug. Watch out, Jeff will come hit you with a giant ampersand.

Comment: That is why you don't store your data with HTML enities in the database.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Oh god no, our data is fine, the API being over-eager to protect from XSS and other attacks is the issue. See [the Safety section here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters).

Comment: I know. And I hate that. I always use dom to insert stuff from an API and on other (non-web) applications it I have to turn of that "feature" anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in version 0.1.76 coming out in tonight (UTC).

Comment: That bug is not completely fixed there is a field recent activity there are the HTML entities again.

Comment: @rekire Mind opening a new question with a screenshot (or more detail) attached? The "Recent activity" section should be similar to the feed which doesn't have any HTML entities issue as far as I know.

Comment: I will open a new question about that soon. I'm quiet busy right now.

Comment: @rekire Scratch that, I found it and fixed it, thanks! :)

Comment: I'm happy to help :-)