# HTML entity in comment options

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I just wanted to upvote a comment in the Android App as I saw a HTML entity in the popup. See also my screenshot:

[image: bug]

Comment: By the way it is a pain to ask questions with a screenshot it took me about 20 minutes to get that managed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This had the same root as cause [this bug from today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212048/wrong-rendering-character-set-for-the-profile-name-in-the-android-app), both have been fixed for next build. Thanks!